# Linking g++ compiled code against libraries created by clang++

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang, homebrew

In my Homebrew installation my libraries are compiled with `clang`, whereas I would like to, for performance reasons, compile my scientific code with `gcc`. In order to understand this problem better, I have created a minimal test:

```
// FILE print.cxx
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void print_message(const std::string& message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

// FILE test.cxx
#include <string>

void print_message(const std::string&);

int main()
{
    std::string message = "Hello World!";
    print_message(message);
    return 0;
}
```

This code I compile with:

```
// SCRIPT compile.sh
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -c print.cxx
g++ test.cxx print.o
```

The example that I have added works, but is it possible to make it work with libraries that are compiled without the `-stdlib=libstdc++` flag and instead use the `libc++`?

Comment: If two objects use two different versions of the standard library, you can't link them together. Not without major pain in the back anyway.

Comment: @n.m. That is what I feared. That would eliminate the my option of using `gcc`, I am afraid.

Comment: You have an option of not using the standard library in the scientific code, or at least not using the binary parts. It should be OK to use header-only parts as long as you don't expose the fact in exported types and function signatures. The standard doesn't say which parts of the standard library are header-only and which ones are compiled, but you can experiment a bit and find out (of course all the usual caveats apply).

Comment: You can also let gcc use libc++...

Comment: @MarcGlisse does it work?

Comment: @nm I haven't tried recently, but I believe it used to work. Of course you don't have a convenient flag like `-stdlib=libc++` and have to pass several flags manually.

Comment: Have you established that gcc outperforms clang for your scientific application? According to Phoronix tests, clang has beaten gcc on SciMark v2.0
benchmarks since clang 3.5 v gcc 4.9. http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=clang-gcc-broadwell&num=1 and http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=clang-37-gcc52&num=1

Comment: @MikeKinghan. 100% sure. In case you are interested I can provide you a test.

Comment: @Chiel No worries, I believe you.